# Restricting `bufdo` to Specific File Types

Tags: key-bindings

I'm currently using a key mapping in Vim that's causing some issues. The mapping is:

```
nmap <buffer> <Leader>tr :silent bufdo TaskWikiBufferLoad<CR>
```

The problem is that the command `TaskWikiBufferLoad` is only applicable to `vimwiki` `filetype`. Thus, this key binding triggers an error message when there is a buffer that is of a different `filetype`.

How can I modify this key mapping so that it only executes `TaskWikiBufferLoad` on buffers of `vimwiki` `filetype`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
nmap <buffer> <Leader>tr :silent bufdo if &filetyoe==#'vimwiki' \| TaskWikiBufferLoad \| endif<CR>
```